# How to use helper methods to access elements from options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionviewhelper

The docs state 
`options_from_collection_for_select(collection, value_method, text_method, selected = nil)` has to have elements that `respond_to?` the `value_method` and the `text_method`.

What if my `collection` is an array of hashes and I need to use some helper methods for `value_method` and `text_method`?

For example,

```
collection = [{
                model: "LaF"
                year: 2016,
                mileage: 1230
             },
             {
                model: "P1",
                year: 2015,
                mileage: 1311
             },
             {
                model: "918",
                year: 2015,
                mileage: 2448
             }
```

]

For example: I want to be able to use the `I18n.interpolate("car.mileage",mileage: element[:mileage])`, method on the `model` key of each element.

TL;DR: How to call hash key methods or other helper methods on `options_from_collection_for_select` elements?

Answer (score 1):

```
options_from_collection_for_select(collection, value_method, ->(element) { I18n.interpolate("car.mileage",mileage: element[:mileage]) })
```

The :value_method and :text_method parameters are methods to be called on each member of collection. The return values are used as the value attribute and contents of each check box tag, respectively. They can also be any object that responds to call, such as a proc, that will be called for each member of the collection to retrieve the value/text.